# Why there is not output in browser?

Tags: node.js

Here is my code:

```
var http = require('http')

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": "json"
    });
    fs.readdir('.', function (error, files) {
        if (error)
            res.end(util.format(error))

        files.forEach(function (file) {
                fs.stat(file, function (erro, stats) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(stats))
                    res.write(JSON.stringify(stats))
                })
            })
    })
}).listen(3000);
console.log("server is running!")
```

When i visit `http://127.0.0.1:3000/`, there is no output, but the console output is:

```
{"dev":0,"mode":16822,"nlink":1,"uid":0,"gid":0,"rdev":0,"ino":0,"size":0,"atime":"2014-11-20T13:36:19.000Z","mtime":"2014-11-20T13:36:19.000Z","ctime":"2014-11-20T13:31:53.000Z"}

{"dev":0,"mode":33206,"nlink":1,"uid":0,"gid":0,"rdev":0,"ino":0,"size":11,"atime":"2014-11-20T13:56:21.000Z","mtime":"2014-11-20T13:56:21.000Z","ctime":"2014-11-20T13:56:21.000Z"}

{"dev":0,"mode":33206,"nlink":1,"uid":0,"gid":0,"rdev":0,"ino":0,"size":844,"atime":"2014-11-20T14:24:04.000Z","mtime":"2014-11-20T14:24:04.000Z","ctime":"2014-11-20T13:32:19.000Z"}

{"dev":0,"mode":16822,"nlink":1,"uid":0,"gid":0,"rdev":0,"ino":0,"size":0,"atime":"2014-11-20T14:03:56.000Z","mtime":"2014-11-20T14:03:56.000Z","ctime":"2014-11-20T13:56:21.000Z"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `res.end()` when you're done with your `res.write` calls.

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": "json"
    });
    fs.readdir('.', function (error, files) {
        if (error)
            res.end(util.format(error))

        var filesLeft = files.length;
        files.forEach(function (file) {
                fs.stat(file, function (erro, stats) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(stats))
                    res.write(JSON.stringify(stats))
                    // Keep track of how many files' fs.stat calls are left
                    if (--filesLeft === 0) {
                        res.end();
                    }
                })
            })
    })
}).listen(3000);
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, i am not familiar with the `callback` and `Asynchronous` in nodejs.